# ArcGIS - how to overwrite "ArcGIS Online World Geocoding service" on search widget

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri

I am new and just exploring ArcGIS API

Wondering how to overwrite the default "ArcGIS Online World Geocoding service" each time i search it calls that service.

I wanted to call our own geocoding service. to add up.. i can't also call my MapServer query using the sandbox using the search widget, but the sample 'Query' sandbox can call our MapServer.

Is there any important things i missed like set-up on our ArcGIS server for the search functionalities to function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better for gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Evan, I will try it now at gis.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: This is the right place for this question, since it has more to do with programming and less to do with GIS usage.